# Wordpress: Add custom fields to post form and handling them

Tags: wordpress

First of all: please, do not offer the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. There is a good reason why I have to do it the following way (I won't bore you with it):

I have a custom post type (created with Custom Post Type UI plugin). I need to add custom HTML form inputs and handle them separately when an admin clicks the "update button" - I need to save the inputs from those values in a separate table.

It must not affect the post saving algorithm. Please, tell me how to add that personally created HTML and how to handle the HTML when the post is updated or created through theme's functions.php file.

Thanks in advance.

In regards to the first comment, the code I have is quite nothing, but here what I am trying to achieve

Hi! Thanks for clarification. Well all I have is this:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'addHtmlToForm' );

function addHTMLToForm(){
  global $post;

  if($post->post_type == 'custom_post_type'){
    echo '<div><input type="text" name="custom_field"></div>';
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_some_post_save_action', 'saveExtraFields');

function saveExtraFields(){
  $custom_field = $_POST['custom_field'];

  //here I will save my fields
}
```

I don't know what hooks and actions that I need to append there should be. I managed to solve the first part of the task - add custom html in the form, but I still can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Hi Timur. Questions asking to provide code / tutorials are off-topic here. Instead, show us what you have done so far to solve the issue and we'll help.

Comment: Side note: A "hooker" is a prostitute. You probably mean "hook" and "hooks."

Answer (score 0):

Done it myself. Thank you very much:

```
add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'addHtmlToForm' );

function addHTMLToForm(){
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'ico'){

        echo '<div><input type="text" name="custom_field"></div>';

    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'saveExtraFields');

function saveExtraFields(){

    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'ico'){
        $custom_field = $_POST['custom_field'];

        echo $custom_field;
    }


}
```